# Why am I getting an errors saying "TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

My problem is that in my code I have many variations of `client.commands.get('help').execute(message, args, version, PREFIX);` but in this case (line 43) I get an error. Here is my code.

````
const client = new Discord.Client();
const token = "Njg5MTcyMzc4NTcxMzc0NzE3.Xm_APA.EcT6EZS5OnhzLA3fUbddsfI63Xw";
const PREFIX = ";";
const version = 'Alpha 1.0.1'

const fs = require('fs');
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("Ready!");
});

client.on('message', message => {
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'test':
            client.commands.get('test').execute(message, args, version);
            break;
        case 'help':
            client.commands.get('help').execute(message, args, version, PREFIX);
            break;
        case 'version':
            message.channel.send('Version: ' + version)
            break;
        case 'convoy':
            if (args[1] = 'sim1') {
                var server = 'Simulation 1 in ETS2'
            } else if (args[1] = 'promods') {
                var server = 'ProMods 1 in ETS2'
            } else if (args[1] = 'us') {
                var server = '[US] Simulation in ATS'
            }
            client.commands.get('convoy').execute(message, args, server);
            break;

        }
});

client.login(token);```
````

Comment: go to the console error output in your browser console and locate the line in the debugger

Comment: I did that and I got  an error saying `TypeError: Discord.RichEmbed is not a constructor`

Comment: @JackKoskie **You've leaked your token!** This means any viewer of this question can take this code and **control your bot from any computer!** Please go to the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discordapp.com/developers/applications/), choose your bot, click the "Bot" tab on the left, and click the Regenerate button under Token to reset your token. Make sure you treat your token like what it is: a combined username and password, one string that allows full unrestricted access to your bot. It should never be accessible in any context by anyone at all other than you.

Comment: ``RichEmbed`` was replaced by ``MessageEmbed`` in Discord.js version 12.  This is likely your issue.  Either change to ``MessageEmbed`` to upgrade, or run ``npm install discord.js@11.6.2``.

And was said, go reset your token.  Don't publish that in the future.

Comment: thanks for all the help =)